# How do I refer to a variable from a method in the same class

Tags: java, class, scope

I surprisingly find this confusing. I must be missing something.

So I have this simple syntax

```
public class OMG{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int hi=2;
        letsDoIt();
        System.out.println(hi);
    }
    public static void letsDoIt(){
        hi+=1;
    }
}
```

Obviously this cause an error, since hi is a local variable.

Judging from my experience from python I added `this`

```
public class OMG{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int hi=2;
        letsDoIt();
        System.out.println(hi);
    }
    public static void letsDoIt(){
        this.hi+=1;
    }
}
```

Which adds extra error when non-static variable cannot be accessed from a static method.

I added  `static`  to hi

```
public class OMG{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        static int hi=2;
        letsDoIt();
        System.out.println(hi);
    }
    public static void letsDoIt(){
        this.hi+=1;
    }
}
```

The compiler scolds me for a illegal expression. I substitute the static with `private` (which some SO answers, recommend) but same error.

Where's my mistake? Is there any way I can solve this, without making global class?

Comment: You must put `static int hi=2;` out of the `main` method body.

Comment: You should start by reading a java tutorial and not base its syntax on some other language.

Comment: I suggest you read up on the concept of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). See also [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm). Then you might want to find out what the keyword `static` means when applied to a method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Unfortunately, I failed to find a java tutorial which covers this. I have a Java book beside me, but nothing about "this", so I made a stab in the dark.

Comment: You couldn't find a book or tutorial that covered the keywords `this` and `static`?

Comment: I tried, there's 2 question on 'this'. It talks about 3 function of 'this' but left out a example of the function of ' this ' in this kind of example.

Comment: That's because your example is not an example of an application of `this`. You need to read between the lines. The tutorials will tell you the purpose of `this` and `static`. You apply it accordingly.

Comment: @Realdeo my answer covers how can you use `this` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare `static` variables inside a method because `static` modifier means that a method or field belongs to the class.

The easiest solution to this problem would be to declare the variable as `static` class variable. Using this approach, you also need to remove `this` from `this.hi` in `lestDoIt` method. The code would be like this:

```
public class OMG {
    static int hi=2;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        letsDoIt();
        System.out.println(hi);
    }
    public static void letsDoIt() {
        hi+=1;
    }
}
```

Another solution may be using a non `static` variable `hi`. This would need you to also remove the `static` modifier to the `letsDoIt` method to access to `hi` field, because `static` methods cannot access to instance fields because, as explained above, `static` means that a method or field belongs to the class and not to a specific object instance of the class.

The solution would be:

```
public class OMG {
    int hi=2;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //note that we have to create a new instance of OMG
        //because, again, static methods cannot access to non-static methods/fields
        OMG omg = new OMG();
        omg.letsDoIt();
        System.out.println(omg.hi);
    }
    public void letsDoIt() {
        this.hi+=1;
    }
}
```

More info:

- [Java Tutorials. Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)
- [Java Tutorials. Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are variables of the class, not its instances. You can't have a static variable inside a method.

To fix this error, move `hi` outside the main method (keeping it static). Also get rid of the `this` in `letsDoIt()`.

```
public class OMG {

    static int hi=2;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        letsDoIt();
        System.out.println(hi);
    }

    public static void letsDoIt() {
        hi+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you give a better explanation about `static` keyword on Java in another question but not here...

Comment: Also remove the `this` reference in the `letsDoIt` method

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't follow. Another question I answered? Do you know which one?

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements causing your issue.

- variable `hi` must be referenced within a shared context between your `main` method and your `letsDoIt` method
- because your `main` method is `static`, and so your `letsDoIt`, the will only have visibility on `static` fields (unless passed an instance as argument, that is)

Hence:

- Declare `hi` as a `static` field of `OMG`:

  ```
  public class OMG {
      static int hi;
      ...
  ```
- Remove the local variable declaration in your `main` method.
- Reference it with `OMG.hi` or just `hi` within a `static` context, **not** with `this.hi` as `this` implies an instance of `Main`, which is not visible from a `static` context

Answer (score 0):

You can not do "this.hi+=1" in a static context and in order to access the hi variable from "letsDoIt()" you have to declare it as a class variable like I did in the code below:

```
public class OMG{
        public static int hi;

        public static void main(String args[]){
            hi=2;
            letsDoIt();
            System.out.println(hi);
        }
        public static void letsDoIt(){
            hi+=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, you can't. As `this` refers to the insance, and in a `static` context there is no instance at all. It will not compile.

Comment: @BackSlash oh right, I forgot that the method was `static`, silly me :).